# Controller per category or one controller for all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my database I have a tables:

```
Products{ProductId, CategoryId, Name} // parent table
Procesors{ProductId...} // 1 to 1
HardDisks{ProductId...} // 1 to 1
MotherBoards{ProductId...} // 1 to 1
Categories{CategoryId, Name, ParentId}
```

And products can be `procesor, hard disk, mother board etc.`

**Option 1:**
Create controllers

```
ProcesorControllers
HardDiskController
MotherBoardController
```

etc.

**Option 2:**

```
CategoryController
ProductController
```

where `ProductController` have a method

```
public ActionResult Index(int categoryId, string category)
{... // return View(products);
```

In aplication scenario I need CRUD, Filter products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD and Filter are generic operations that are agnostic of any category of products. Your application may scale such that newer products are added after a while.

With that in mind, I would say **Option 1** will not scale. Imagine a code change each time a new product is added.

**Option 2** is what I would try to lean towards. It will also help you write non-duplicated code, lesser code.

Comment: I understand that I will get less code with option 2 but each product (cpu, hdd, mobo etc.) has different properties and I can't use just one detail view for each because I need to list all those properties. What would be solution if I use option 2? Can I have views without action method where I can pass model object and reder it?

Comment: You could have one Partial View per product category, if you need to display product specific property. Models/Views can be extended to one per product. I always like Fat Models/Thin Controllers. Hence my preference to Option 1. Controllers need not be bloated because of this.

Comment: So I can make `Partial View per product category` as you said. Is it good to keep it in shared folder of project as this is partials and doesn't have it's model object?

Comment: I use Razor, and I can have partial views along with other view (`~/Views/Products/_Processor.cshtml`). Doesn't have to be in Shared. And I think in your case, these views will be strongly typed, so you would need the models referred.

Comment: So to make some summary I just test it and it is probably final solution for my problem. When I select some `product` I get it from database and return model object to view. As `Procesor` is inherited from `Product` I can pass it to view which use `Product` as a model. Based on `CategoryId` I use `@Html.Partial("ProcesorPartialView", (Model as BST.TST.Domain.Entities.Procesor))` to display procesor specific information. Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: @1110 - Yes, thats roughly what I'm suggesting. Please share your test results once you are done.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25887/discussion-between-srikanth-venugopalan-and-1110)

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting it controllers are supposed to act as containers for a given context, so grouping your products in the ProductController seems logical.

However this is personal preference. Things you need to think about is maintainability of massive controllers, and the urls you want to generate when accessing these endpoints.